# Can I treat a categorical variable (such as income categories) as a numeric predictor?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, references, ordinal-data

Suppose that I have a survey question about income level, with options like:

Less than 10,000
 10,001 - 20,000
 Greater than 20.000

Then could I assume a numeric value of 5,000, 15,000, and 20,000 for each of my options above when I run a regression? Are there any references that talk about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That would not be very appropriate.  If it is a dependent variable it should be treated as ordinal.  If an independent variable then represent it as categorical with three levels, requiring 2 indicator variables.  I'm surprised so few categories were used.